# What happens in the GPU between the call to gl.drawArrays() to g.readPixels?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

Changing the Title in the hopes of being more accurate.

We have some code which runs several programs in succession by calling `drawArrays()` . The output textures from each stage are fed into the next and so on.

After the final call to draw, a call to `readPixels()` is made.
This call takes an enormous amount of time (for an output of < 1000 floats). I have measured a `readPixels` of that size in isolation which takes 1 or 2 ms. However in our case we see a delay of about 1500ms.

So we conjectured that the actual computation must have not started until we called `readPixels()`. To test this theory and to force the computation, we placed a call to `gl.flush()` after each `gl.drawxx()`. This made no difference.

So we replaced that with a call to `gl.finish()`. Again no difference. We finally replaced it with a call to `getError()`.  Still no difference.

Can we conclude that gpu actually does not draw anything unless the framebuffer is read from? Can we force it to do so?